# How to install color schemas for Kate running on GNOME

Tags: colors, gnome3, theme, kate

How do I install schemas(like [this one](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/DarkOxygen?content=140718); for syntax highlighting, etc) for Kate (which is originally for KDE) running on GNOME 3? Trying to install with the install.sh script took no effect. Also, if you happen to know any good schemas for Kate (for Python), please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at

[Where to get Kate color schemes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20902/where-to-get-kate-color-schemes)

and see if it has any answers for you.

Are you saying that appending the schema and syntaxhighlighting files to `~/.kde/share/config/kateschemarc` and `~/.kde/share/config/katesyntaxhighlightingrc` respectively using `cat >>` does not work in GNOME 3?