# Where to get Kate color schemes?

Tags: colors, kate, theme, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know where one could find some good Kate color schemes for syntax highlighting?

The only ones that I found that work fine are [zenburn](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/?content=66209) and [mdark](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/mdark?content=142774).

Besides those two, I couldn't find anything else (that works). There were a few other schemes on [kde-looks](http://kde-look.org/) but I couldn't make them work.. (couldn't import them)

Does anyone know of any other working kate color schemes? Thank you.

Comment: Related post [Default Color Schemas](http://kate-editor.org/2012/11/07/default-color-schemas/). Check out [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) and get it for Kate from <git://github.com/hayalci/kde-colors-solarized.git>

Answer (score 10):

Please see:

http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/darK+-+A+Kate+Syntax+Highlighting+Theme?content=53388

http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/DarkOxygen?content=140718

They might help.

Also,

https://askubuntu.com/questions/19005/using-oblivion-color-scheme-from-gedit-in-kate

There are three dead links at the bottom of this email

http://lists.kde.org/?l=kde-bugs-dist&m=121052554705534&w=2

which might live elsewhere in case that helps.

I am on a similar search as you for LaTeX in kile, in my case, and will share my results here. There appear to be two aspects for kate/kile

1. Schema which is independent of the file being edited; and
2. Syntax highlighting which is file and language dependent.

One needs both. The syntax highlighting might need tweaking depending on language and keywords used. Indeed it might not exist for some languages.

Over and above this, there is the general KDE theme which includes colour schemes and styles. These are applicable to all application windows. So, there appear to be five components in all:

(a) Theme
(b) Colour Scheme
(c) Style
(d) Kate or Kile schema
(e) Kate or Kile syntax highlighting

HTH.